# Trying to make every number possibility with digits from array

Tags: c++, arrays

I have the following array:
`int a[3]={1, 2, 3};`
**note: I don't know how many elements the array has.**

I want to output

> 123; 132; 213; 231; 312; 321.

However I don't know how many digits are found in the array. Also the same digit can't be repeated.

Comment: You might be looking for [`std::next_permutation`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/next_permutation)

Answer (score 2):

As a comment said, it sounds like you want [std::next_permutation](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/next_permutation), here's how to use it:

```
int main()
{
    std::vector<int> a{ 1, 2, 3 };

    std::sort(a.begin(), a.end());
    do {
        std::cout << a << "; ";
    } while (std::next_permutation(a.begin(), a.end()));

    return 0;
}
```

Note that you need an overload of `operator<<()`:

```
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& s, const std::vector<int>& v)
{
    for (auto&& item : v)
        s << item;
    return s;
}
```

The output of this program is

> 123; 132; 213; 231; 312; 321;

You can even make a little utility routine:

```
void permutations(std::ostream& s, std::vector<int> a)
{
    std::sort(a.begin(), a.end());
    do {
        s << a << "; ";
    } while (std::next_permutation(a.begin(), a.end()));
}

permutations(std::cout, a);
std::cout << "\n";
permutations(std::cout, { 3, 1, 4, 2 });
```

Answer (score -1):

So its ever permutation. You have N! permuations.

It's easiest to write the function recursively, enumerate the first digit, then then second from N-1, the third from N-2 and so on.